# ParticlesJS component in React is hidden with media queries but not coming back to display

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, media-queries, particles.js

I am using the ParticlesJS package for my ReactJS application. It displays at the beginning. I want to hide it when the screen size is under 600px. It sets the display to none, however when the screen is resized back above 600px, the particles element doesn't set display back to block, so it's not displayed again.

html/jsx:

```
<div className="particles-container">
  <Particles params={particleParams} className="particles" />
    <div className="home-banner-content"> 
      <img src="./src/style/img/logo_banner.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .particles-container .particles {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .particles-container .particles {
    display: block;
  }  
}
```

Comment: There should be a comma between class names when applying the same styling to multiple classes `.particles-container, .particles`. Also with that current code, remember that at exactly 600px both styles will be applied. In this case the one below will override the one above, but just a reminder.

Comment: ^In addition to my answer, this is a very valid point. Kindly use this.

Comment: I only wanted to apply the styling to the .particles class. I thought that's the way to specify the child class? Thanks for pointing out the case where the screen is exactly 600px! Thank you for the answer @Jayce444.

Comment: @ongelo If you're wanting to specify the children in CSS you want the child selector: `>`. Have a look here for a description: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging in a bit I saw that the Canvas's height is set to 0 when `display: none;` is set via the media query.

I'll have to dig in more to get the correct answer to as to why that might be happening. Will return with an update to this answer with a proper explanation regarding this.

Continuing, when your media query sets `display: block;` the height of the canvas still remains 0 and thus you are unable to see it.

To fix this you can either listen to window resize events inside the javascript code (in case you're resizing).

But in case you're going to fix this for mobile then you can check for window width inside the javascript itself and conditionally render the Particles component.

Also, if you provide a "fixed" height to the Particles component as a prop, your media query will work.

Here, you can see a demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/rw8666x11o

Comment: It worked perfectly when I set the height of the Particles! Thank you